# Enable metrics in wildfly domain setup

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-18

I am new to wildfly configuration & was trying to enable microprofile smallrye metrics in wildfly for domain mode. Using clustered [docker](https://github.com/SleepingTalent/wildfly-domain-docker.git) repo, I started domain & host controller locally for wildfly 18. Added following extension & submodule to **full** profile using below cli commands.

1. `/extension=org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config-smallrye:add`
2. `/extension=org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics-smallrye:add`
3. `/profile=full/subsystem=microprofile-config-smallrye:add`
4. `/profile=full/subsystem=microprofile-metrics-smallrye:add`

While executing 4th command, it throws error saying host controller need http interface.

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"host-failure-descriptions" => {"4000d68ab8c2" => "WFLYCTL0369: Required capabilities are not available:
    org.wildfly.management.http.extensible in context 'profile=full'; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /host=4000d68ab8c2/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface"}},
    "rolled-back" => true,
    "result" => {}
}
```

I read [wildfly 18 docs](https://docs.wildfly.org/18/Admin_Guide.html#domain-controller-configuration) which says

```
A host acting as the Domain Controller must expose a management interface on an address accessible to the other hosts in the domain. Exposing an HTTP(S) management interface is not required, but is recommended as it allows the Administration Console to work
```

I checked `http-interface` is declared in `host-master.xml`. And in slave , I added  below code which points to HTTP management port. Also, I manually added extension & subsystem in domain.xml

```
<domain-controller>
   <remote protocol="http-remoting" host="192.168.0.101" port="9990" username="slave" security-realm="SlaveRealm"/>
</domain-controller>
```

But when I start the setup, slave is disconnected from domain. Metrics in standalone setup is working fine, but domain mode I am facing some issues. Any leads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smallrye wildfly metrics is not supported in domain mode.

https://wildfly.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/196266-wildfly-user